# Duda con procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, asp

Hola chicos tengo una duda, tengo un código en ASP  en el que llama a un procedimiento almacenado este procedimiento lo que hace es actualizar mis datos en mi BD, pero al momento de intentar actualizar no lo hace:

```
<%@Language=VBScript%>
<%option explicit%>

 <!--#include virtual="sub_bd.asp"-->

 <%

  dim i, Q
  dim nombre_tipo, msj,id

' obtener valores
  nombre_tipo = request.form("tipo_auto")
  id = request.form("id_tipo")

  response.write ("nombre_tipo ->"& nombre_tipo &"<br />")
  response.write ("id ->"& id &"<br />")
  response.end

  msj = exeDBT("EXEC [dbo].[SP_Arriendo_TipoAuto_U] '"& nombre_tipo &"''"& id &"';")

  response.redirect("index2.asp?m=27")

  %>
```

Comment: Revise si la los valores de *(`nombre_tipo` y `id`)* enviados al procedimiento son correctos. Puede que tenga un error de consistencia de datos...

Comment: ¿Da algún error cuando se ejecuta? Por otro lado, si puedes poner el procedimiento podríamos ver si hay algún error.